# Spring Boot 2.3.4: Bug with JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(String)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, nimbus-jose-jwt, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I found an odd behavior with JWT parsing and JwtValidators.

Scenario:

- Spring Boot OIDC client (for now a tiny web app, only displaying logged in user and some OIDC objects provided by Spring)
- Custom `JwtDecoderFacotry<ClientRegistration>` for ID-Token validation
- `JwtValidatorFactory` based on `JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(String)`

This worked well with Spring Boot version <= 2.2.10.

Debugging:

- `NimbusJwtDecoder` (JAR spring-security-oauth2-jose) uses claim set converters. The 'iss' (issuer) claim is handled as URL.
- `JwtIssuerValidator` (internally created by `JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(String)`) wraps a `JwtClaimValidator<String>`.
- this one finally calls `equals()` that is always `false` - it compares String with URL.

My current workaround is not calling `JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer()` but just using the validators `new JwtTimestampValidator()` and an own implementation of `OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>` (with wrapping `JwtClaimValidator<URL>`).

Anyone else having trouble with this?

--Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Pull Request is created.